# nginx reverse proxy nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want:
(1)  `https://example.com` to serve static content using SSL
(2)  `https://sub.example.com/myapp` to serve dynamic content from NodeJS using SSL.

I have a domain example.com and one subdomain sub.example.com.  I have a Docker container that has nginx and a nodejs app in it.  Using Ubuntu on Digital Ocean.

I am getting 502 Bad Gateway errors.  Not sure if this CAN work or if it can, how to fix it.

- The nodejs app listens on 8080 (no host specified, no SSL)
- Nginx listens on 80 and 443 for example.com but redirects all http (80) requests to https (443)
- Nginx listens on 443 for sub.example.com.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      - ./data/nginx/html:/etc/nginx/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
  node:
    image: node:11
    volumes:
      - ./data/node:/usr/local/src/node
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    working_dir: /usr/local/src/node/myapp
    command: node server.js
```

nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location /myapp {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you run ```sudo tail /var/log/nginx/error.log``` and include the logs in your question as well?

Comment: It's running inside docker so i'm not sure how i can access the logs.

Comment: 2019/10/13 19:08:11 [error] 8#8: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: sub.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "sub.example.com"